# How to detect file ends in newline?

Tags: svn, bash, text-files

Over at [Can you modify text files when committing to subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664/can-you-modify-text-files-when-committing-to-subversion) [Grant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664/can-you-modify-text-files-when-committing-to-subversion#38666) suggested that I block commits instead.

However I don't know how to check a file ends with a newline. How can you detect that the file ends with a newline?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**[@Konrad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746/how-to-detect-file-ends-in-newline#39185)**: tail does not return an empty line. I made a file that has some text that doesn't end in newline and a file that does. Here is the output from tail:

```
$ cat test_no_newline.txt
this file doesn't end in newline$ 

$ cat test_with_newline.txt
this file ends in newline
$
```

Though I found that tail has get last byte option. So I modified your script to:

```
#!/bin/sh
c=`tail -c 1 $1`
if [ "$c" != "" ]; then
    echo "no newline"
fi
```

Comment: This answer is not optimal because I have no clue which Konrad you are referring to.

Comment: `[ "$c" != "" ]` is `false` for completely empty files which is contrary to what I'd expect.

Comment: This also fails if the last byte is a null byte. You cannot distinguish between "empty" and "ends with a newline" in a command substitution, which trims the final newline.

Answer (score 35):

Here is a useful bash function:

```
function file_ends_with_newline() {
    [[ $(tail -c1 "$1" | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]
}
```

You can use it like:

```
if ! file_ends_with_newline myfile.txt
then
    echo "" >> myfile.txt
fi
# continue with other stuff that assumes myfile.txt ends with a newline
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer; it works correctly for empty files, files ending in a null byte, and regular files. The pipe to `wc -l` is kind of unattractive but it does exactly the right thing -- it counts the number of newlines in the last byte of the file. If it's not one, the file does not end with a newline.

Answer (score 20):

Or even simpler:

```
#!/bin/sh
test "$(tail -c 1 "$1")" && echo "no newline at eof: '$1'"
```

But if you want a more robust check:

```
test "$(tail -c 1 "$1" | wc -l)" -eq 0 && echo "no newline at eof: '$1'"
```

Comment: Not trustworthy, as it cannot tell the difference between EOL and any other space character.

Comment: @akim It is now fixed.

Comment: This still fails e.g. if the last character is a null byte.

Comment: Fine. An extra check for that.

Comment: for those that don't know `test`, this is the same as: [[ "$(tail -c 1 "$1")" ]] && echo "no newline at eof: '$1'"

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like this as your pre-commit script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
    $last = $_;
}

if (! ($last =~ m/\n$/)) {
    print STDERR "File doesn't end with \\n!\n";
    exit 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using only `bash`:

```
x=`tail -n 1 your_textfile`
if [ "$x" == "" ]; then echo "empty line"; fi
```

(Take care to copy the whitespaces correctly!)

@grom:

> tail does not return an empty line

Damn. My test file didn't end on `\n` but on `\n\n`. Apparently `vim` can't create files that don't end on `\n` (?). Anyway, as long as the “get last byte” option works, all's well.

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me:

```
tail -n 1 /path/to/newline_at_end.txt | wc --lines
# according to "man wc" : --lines - print the newline counts
```

So wc counts number of newline chars, which is good in our case.
The oneliner prints either 0 or 1 according to presence of newline at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

A complete Bash solution with only `tail` command, that also deal correctly with empty files.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Return 0 if file $1 exists and ending by end of line character,
# else return 1
[[ -s "$1" && -z "$(tail -c 1 "$1")" ]]
```

- `-s "$1"` checks if the file is not empty
- `-z "$(tail -c 1 "$1")"` checks if its last (existing) character is end of line character
- the all `[[...]]` conditional expression is returned

You can also defined this Bash function to use it in your scripts.

```sh
# Return 0 if file $1 exists and ending by end of line character,
# else return 1
check_ending_eol() {
    [[ -s "$1" && -z "$(tail -c 1 "$1")" ]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `read` command can not read a line without newline.

```sh
if tail -c 1 "$1" | read -r line; then
  echo "newline"
fi
```

Another answer.

```sh
if [ $(tail -c 1 "$1" | od -An -b) = 012 ]; then
  echo "newline"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming up with a correction to my own answer.

Below should work in all cases with no failures:

```
nl=$(printf '\012')
nls=$(wc -l "${target_file}")
lastlinecount=${nls%% *}
lastlinecount=$((lastlinecount+1))
lastline=$(sed ${lastlinecount}' !d' "${target_file}")
if [ "${lastline}" = "${nl}" ]; then
    echo "${target_file} ends with a new line!"
else
    echo "${target_file} does NOT end with a new line!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last character of the file using `tail -c 1`.

```
   my_file="/path/to/my/file"

   if [[ $(tail -c 1 "$my_file") != "" ]]; then
      echo "File doesn't end with a new line: $my_file"
   fi
```