# How to list all files in the Git index without newline at end of file

Tags: git, bash, awk

I have a merge tool which unfortunately removes newlines at the end of the files. So after I've used this tool, I need to check if any of the files in the Git index have their trailing newlines removed.

`git diff --cached` displays these trailing newline removals, but it also prints the full diff. I'd like to get a more concise view which only lists the file names of the changed files in the Git index which are lacking the trailing newline.

I tried to combine `git diff --name-only` and `git grep`, but I can't find the a regular expression to detect files without newline at the end of file. Expressions including `\Z` don't seem to be recognized by `git grep` even with extended regular expressions (`-E`).

Comment: sounds like you need to tell your merge tool to stop doing that. Does it have an option to control that behaviour?

Comment: This is a bit off-topic, but if you are interested, I'm having this problem because [TortoiseSVN stopped shipping recent versions of TortoiseMerge as standalone tool](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=2876076)

Comment: You might want to check out meld: http://meldmerge.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746/how-to-detect-file-ends-in-newline) with some Bash magic eventually got me to this solution:

```
for file in $(git diff --cached --name-only); do test $(tail -c 1 $file) && echo $file; done
```