# Linux - check if there is an empty line at the end of a file

Tags: linux, eof, carriage-return

*NOTE: this question used to be worded differently, using “with/out newline” instead of “with/out empty line”*

I have two files, one with an empty line and one without:

**File: text_without_empty_line**

```
$root@kali:/home#cat text_without_empty_line
This is a Testfile
This file does not contain an empty line at the end
$root@kali:/home#
```

**File: text_with_empty_line**

```
$root@kali:/home#cat text_with_empty_line
This is a Testfile
This file does contain an empty line at the end

$root@kali:/home#
```

Is there a command or function to check if a file has an empty line at the end?
I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746/how-to-detect-file-ends-in-newline?answertab=active#tab-top) solution, but it does not work for me. (EDIT: IGNORE: A solution with preg_match and PHP would be fine as well.)

Comment: Your second example seems to contain 2 newlines at the because it does not only wrap the shell prompt to the next line but also includes an empty line. Is that important or unintended?

Comment: oh you are right, my console output was incorrect, i change it. Thx!

Comment: So you are really asking, is the last line empty.

Comment: @jww not a duplicate, especially after my edit

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Olivier Pirson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63398061/3995440) is neater than the one I posted here originally (it also handles empty files correctly). I edited my solution to match his.

In bash:

```sh
newline_at_eof()
{
    if [[ -s "$1" && -z "$(tail -c 1 "$1")" ]]
    then
        echo "Newline at end of file!"
    else
        echo "No newline at end of file!"
    fi
}
```

As a shell script that you can call (paste it into a file, `chmod +x <filename>` to make it executable):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -s "$1" && -z "$(tail -c 1 "$1")" ]]
then
    echo "Newline at end of file!"
else
    echo "No newline at end of file!"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide the whole script pls and describe how to use it, i am a newbie to bash scripting. I don't get any output.

Comment: Make sure your interpreter is `#!/bin/sh` at the top of the file, then just add the function and then `newline_at_eof "$1"` after the function. Or just use the following as line 2 and forget the function `test $(tail -c 1 $1) && printf "no newline at eof: $1\n" || printf "newline at eof: $1\n"`

Comment: Thank you, now the script works. But i always get "Newline at end of file!"... even on files which contain only one single line!

Comment: I edited my answer to include the whole script. It should work on files with an arbitrary number of lines (tested on Debian stretch amd64, bash 4.3-14+b1, coreutils 8.23-4).

Comment: @EdwardBlack You should always get `newline at eof` even with a 1 line file because POSIX specifies that all `files` end with a newline (regardless of the number of lines). Note: that doesn't mean they will. There are a lot of editors that write non-POSIX compliant line endings.

Comment: I already read about this, but in my case my files are for a server configuration and it won't work if there is a space, tab or newline at the end, so i have to remove them.

Comment: (@Fred `else` after an `exit` is superfluous.)

Comment: Isn't that what they call *re-entrant* (you leave and then come back to finish the `if` block ? `:)`

Comment: I think it's better to use `echo` instead of `exit` since the later indicates whether [there's an error with the process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47177028/3184351).

Comment: `exit` is sometimes useful if comparing the exit status to some value is easier than comparing the output of the program (e.g. integer vs. string comparison). Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40484670/3995440) explaisn quite well that there are no real conventions for exit codes rather than 0 and 2. For example, `diff` returns 1 if the files differ. That's hardly an error with the process.

Comment: Empty file is a special case which must be check separately. One way is to complete by:
if [[ -s "$1" && -z "$(tail -c 1 "$1")" ]]

Answer (score 33):

Just type:

```
cat -e nameofyourfile
```

If there is a newline it will end with `$` symbol.
If not, it will end with a `%` symbol.

Comment: I get a `$` with new lines but don't seem to get `%` when there isn't one. Trying both BSD cat and GNU cat

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746/how-to-detect-file-ends-in-newline?lq=1).

```bash
#!/bin/bash
x=`tail -n 1 "$1"`
if [ "$x" == "" ]; then
    echo "Newline at end of file!"
else
    echo "No Newline at end of file!"
fi
```

IMPORTANT: Make sure that you have the right to execute and read the script!
`chmod 555 script`

USAGE:

```
./script text_with_newline        OUTPUT: Newline at end of file!
./script text_without_newline     OUTPUT: No Newline at end of file!
```

Comment: This checks whether the last *two* characters are newlines. A much more interesing problem, which probably most people assume you are asking, is how to identify invalid text files which have text after the final newline.

Answer (score 2):

The `\Z` meta-character means the absolute end of the string.

```
if (preg_match('#\n\Z#', file_get_contents('foo.txt'))) {
    echo 'New line found at the end';
}
```

So here you are looking at a new line at the absolute end of the string. `file_get_contents` will not add anything at the end. BUT it will load the entire file into memory; if your file is not too big, its okay, otherwise you'll have to bring a new solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you. But I just tried it and i always get "New line found at the end", even though there is no newline. Try it by yourselve.

Comment: I always try before submitting. It works properly. Maybe it's your text editor that automatically end a new line at the end, like `nano` does.

Comment: Which text editor should i use instead of `nano`?

Comment: `vi` for exemple.
Press `i` to be in edit mode, `esc` to exit edit mode, and `:qw` to exit program saving changes.

Comment: I created a single liner with `vi` but i still get "New line found at the end", are you sure that your code works properly?

Comment: Did you copy exactly my code ? Because I've try it again and again and it just works.

Comment: On the bottom of the screen in vi, you should see "[Incomplete last line]" meaning there is actually no new line at the end.

Comment: I made a screenshot, unfortunattely i don't know how to upload pictures in the comment section, so i uploaded it to pasteall: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=98003 There is no `[incomplete last line]`

Comment: This is super weird. If you do `php -r 'echo nl2br(file_get_contents("/var/www/html/textohne_newline"));'` , do you see a "<br />" at the end ?

Comment: yes there is a `<br />` at the end if i do this, hmm weird. Do you know why this is added?

Comment: Maybe check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050640/vim-disable-automatic-newline-at-end-of-file

Comment: If your question is answered, don't forget to mark the correct answer.