# return values from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, echo, return-value

I want to create a Bash file that returns a value.
Meaning, in script script_a.bash I have a certain calculation, and script script_b.bash will call it.

script_a.bash:

```
return $1*5
```

script_b.bash:

```
a_value=./script_a.bash 3
```

when a_value will be 15.

I read a little bit about that, and saw that there's no "return" in bash, but something like this can be done in functions using "echo". I don't want to use functions, I need a generic script to use in multiple places.

Is it possible to return a value from a different script?

Comment: Use `exit rc` instead of `return rc`.

Comment: It's not possible to return a value from a bash script. If you echo the result, the calling process can grab it. A numeric can be returned with `exit` but that's not recommended as this is represents a status code (and also some codes are reserved - so 'should' not be used).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use command substitution to capture the output of `echo`, and use arithmetic expression to count the result:

script_a.bash:

```
echo $(( $1 * 5 ))
```

script_b.bash

```
a_value=$( script_a.bash 3 )
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `return` or `exit`, as they're for indicating the success/failure of a script, not the output.

Write your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $(( $1 * 5 ))
```

Access the value:

```
a_value=$(./script_a.bash 3)
```

That is, use a `$(command substitution)` in the consuming code to capture the output of the script.

Comment: What if the script prints multiple output (e.g. some info via `printf`) and we only want the last output? e.g. inside a POSIX script if `bash` is found run `bash -c` with subscript, and this subscript has if statement that would alter the behaviour of the POSIX script?

Comment: Command substitution will capture standard output, so the script can either make use of standard error (e.g. output status messages to `>&2`), or you can get the last line of the output using e.g.  `last_line=$(tail -n1 <<<"$a_value")`. There are several answers on here explaining other methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use exit rc;, but keep in mind that conventionally in *nix 0 is a successful result, any positive value is an error code. 
Is it an option to call

```
echo <your_value>;
```

and redirect output to the next binary called in the chain?

Comment: Also note `exit` status is limited to 0-255 - so OP's `$1` could only be max of 85 :-)