# Testing "tail -c 1" in bash

Tags: bash, tail

In [Linux - check if there is an empty line at the end of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34943632/3184351), some posts make use of `[[ ]]` and `==` to compare characters.

I would like to write a one-line command for detecting if there's no newline at EOF, and I came across this little problem.

In the output of `echo`, there's `\n` at the end.

```sh
$ echo echo | od -c           
0000000   e   c   h   o  \n
0000005
$ echo -n echo | od -c           
0000000   e   c   h   o
0000004
```

If I put `[[ ]]` and `==` together, then I don't get the expected output.

```
$ [[ `echo echo | tail -c1` == "\n" ]] && echo true
$ [[ `echo echo | tail -c1` != "\n" ]] && echo true
true
$ [[ `echo -n echo | tail -c1` != "\n" ]] && echo true
true
```

As shown by `od -c`, the output of `echo echo | tail -c1` is `\n`, and `[[ "\n" == "\n" ]] && true` would return `true`, so I expect the first command gives `true`.  However, why is it evaluated to empty string?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: No, the output of `echo | tail -c 1 | od -c` is `\n`.

Comment: @tripleee You're right.  I didn't know that before reading the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is clearly stated in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, **with any trailing newlines deleted.**

Turn on the `-x` flag to see what happens clearly:

```
$ set -x
$ [[ `echo echo | tail -c 1` == '\n' ]]
++ tail -c 1
++ echo echo
+ [[ '' == \\\n ]]
$
$ echo "$(echo)"
++ echo
+ echo ''
```

And as a sidenote, even if trailing newlines weren't trimmed your comparison wouldn't return true, because `'\n'` is not a line feed, but literally a backslash followed by the letter `n`. You should use `$'\n'` to get an actual line feed.

Comment: I'm [using Zsh](https://sunlightmedia.org/bash-vs-zsh) for better Git autocompletion, and I see the lines coming in this order: `+zsh:3> [[+zsh:3> echo echo`, `+zsh:3> [[+zsh:3> tail -c 1`, `+zsh:3> [[ '' == \\n ]]`.  (lines 1-2 interchanged, only two backslashes at line 3)

Comment: Nvm.  You may forget about that.  I've chosen "bash" since the main problem is not "zsh"-specfic.

Answer (score 1):

As for a solution, you can use the following:

```
$ printf 'test\n' | perl -0777ne'exit(/\n\z/?0:1)' || echo "Missing line feed" >&2

$ printf 'test'   | perl -0777ne'exit(/\n\z/?0:1)' || echo "Missing line feed" >&2
Missing line feed
```

or

```
$ printf 'test\n' | perl -0777ne'die("Missing line feed\n") if !/\n\z/'

$ printf 'test'   | perl -0777ne'die("Missing line feed\n") if !/\n\z/'
Missing line feed
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.  I would learn Perl if I have time in the future.